# Display a field if it's different than 0, else don't display it - in a Crystal Reports formula

Tags: c#, ado.net, crystal-reports-2010, sql-view

For one double field in Crystal Reports, I wish to write up formula where if that field is equal to zero, it should display as "--", else the actual value should be shown.

What I have written is :

```
If (IsNull({View_journal.debit})) then  
    "--"
Else {View_journal.debit}
```

but the formula doesn't execute at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is not the same as 0.
Your formula should be something like

```
if 
   {View_journal.debit} = 0 
then
    "--"
else 
    ToText({View_journal.debit}, 2)
```

EDIT:
`ToText` converts `debit` value to string with 2 decimal places.

Comment: it still don't work . it say that i must enter a string value in else statement

Comment: Thank you very much  @Nino . i apreciate your help  . the solution works fine . thank you again